# R data.table- converting multiple measurements on the same date to variables: wt1 wt2, etc.. (similar to dcast)

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data set:

```
    id  date        wt      ht
    1   2/3/2020    2.2     1.5
    1   2/3/2020    2.3     1.45
    1   2/3/2020    2.4     1.54
    2   2/5/2020    2.3     1.8
    2   2/5/2020    2.2     1.99
    3   2/8/2020    3.2     2.8
    3   2/8/2020    3.4     2.9
```

and would like to convert it to the following

```
    id  date        wt1     wt2    wt3  ht1  ht2  ht3
    1   2/3/2020    2.2     2.3    2.4  1.5  1.45 1.54
    2   2/5/2020    2.3     2.2    NA   1.8  1.99
    3   2/8/2020    3.2     3.4    NA   2.8  2.9
```

I've tried dcast :

```
   dcast(data, id + date ~ wt + ht)
```

but have not end up with the intended result. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With `dcast` from `data.table`, it would be possible to specify multiple 'value' columns in `value.var` and in the formula, specify the sequence based on 'id', 'date' with `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), id + date ~ rowid(id, date), value.var = c('wt', 'ht'), sep = "")
#   id     date wt1 wt2 wt3 ht1  ht2  ht3
#1:  1 2/3/2020 2.2 2.3 2.4 1.5 1.45 1.54
#2:  2 2/5/2020 2.3 2.2  NA 1.8 1.99   NA
#3:  3 2/8/2020 3.2 3.4  NA 2.8 2.90   NA
```

---

Or another option is `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(id, date)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(wt, ht), names_sep="")
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#    id date       wt1   wt2   wt3   ht1   ht2   ht3
#  <int> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 2/3/2020   2.2   2.3   2.4   1.5  1.45  1.54
#2     2 2/5/2020   2.3   2.2  NA     1.8  1.99 NA   
#3     3 2/8/2020   3.2   3.4  NA     2.8  2.9  NA
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), date = c("2/3/2020", 
"2/3/2020", "2/3/2020", "2/5/2020", "2/5/2020", "2/8/2020", "2/8/2020"
), wt = c(2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 3.2, 3.4), ht = c(1.5, 1.45, 
1.54, 1.8, 1.99, 2.8, 2.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: I can get this to work for one variable at a time (I.e. wt), but can't get it to work on both wt and ht

Comment: @boodaloo1 can you check whether you have loaded `data.table`, as it is working for me

Comment: I have data.table loaded. I get the following error: "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds".

Comment: @boodaloo1 i used  `packageVersion('data.table')#
[1] ‘1.12.8’`.  Also, added `tidyverse` option

Comment: @boodaloo1 are you getting the error based on the same example showed.  Can you use the data in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `reshape` from base R:

```
reshape(transform(data,time = ave(id,id,FUN=seq)),dir="wide",idvar = c("id","date"),sep="")

  id     date wt1 ht1 wt2  ht2 wt3  ht3
1  1 2/3/2020 2.2 1.5 2.3 1.45 2.4 1.54
4  2 2/5/2020 2.3 1.8 2.2 1.99  NA   NA
6  3 2/8/2020 3.2 2.8 3.4 2.90  NA   NA
```